# Opsworks instance fails to start : Status: start_failed: No such cookbook: apt

Tags: json, amazon-web-services, templates, aws-cloudformation, aws-opsworks

I have created a cloudformation template that creates opsworks resources: stack, layer, app and instance. I added my cookbook to S3 and I tested my template, all the resources are successfully created except the opsworks instance and I get this error :

```
CREATE_FAILED   AWS::OpsWorks::Instance     MyInstance  ff45a8d0-9adf-40a4-a049-f2329a9fa1f0 failed. Status=start_failed
```

Could any one tell me where should I check, and what is the cause of that? 
Also, I have tried so many instance types, memory optimised but still getting the error. Please Help. Thank you very much.

Here are the logs :

```
[2016-12-15T13:58:12+00:00] INFO: directory[/var/chef/runs/a679dc7b-3cbf-4d43-9bc8-5ae0223d3b5f] created directory /var/chef/runs/a679dc7b-3cbf-4d43-9bc8-5ae0223d3b5f
[2016-12-15T13:58:12+00:00] INFO: Processing directory[/var/chef/runs/a679dc7b-3cbf-4d43-9bc8-5ae0223d3b5f/data_bags] action create (/var/lib/aws/opsworks/cache.internal/cookbooks/aws_opsworks_custom_run/providers/default.rb line 92)
[2016-12-15T13:58:12+00:00] INFO: directory[/var/chef/runs/a679dc7b-3cbf-4d43-9bc8-5ae0223d3b5f/data_bags] created directory /var/chef/runs/a679dc7b-3cbf-4d43-9bc8-5ae0223d3b5f/data_bags
[2016-12-15T13:58:12+00:00] INFO: Processing directory[/var/chef/runs/a679dc7b-3cbf-4d43-9bc8-5ae0223d3b5f/nodes] action create (/var/lib/aws/opsworks/cache.internal/cookbooks/aws_opsworks_custom_run/providers/default.rb line 97)
[2016-12-15T13:58:12+00:00] INFO: directory[/var/chef/runs/a679dc7b-3cbf-4d43-9bc8-5ae0223d3b5f/nodes] created directory /var/chef/runs/a679dc7b-3cbf-4d43-9bc8-5ae0223d3b5f/nodes
[2016-12-15T13:58:12+00:00] INFO: Processing template[/var/chef/runs/a679dc7b-3cbf-4d43-9bc8-5ae0223d3b5f/client.rb] action create (/var/lib/aws/opsworks/cache.internal/cookbooks/aws_opsworks_custom_run/providers/default.rb line 106)
[2016-12-15T13:58:12+00:00] INFO: template[/var/chef/runs/a679dc7b-3cbf-4d43-9bc8-5ae0223d3b5f/client.rb] created file /var/chef/runs/a679dc7b-3cbf-4d43-9bc8-5ae0223d3b5f/client.rb
[2016-12-15T13:58:12+00:00] INFO: template[/var/chef/runs/a679dc7b-3cbf-4d43-9bc8-5ae0223d3b5f/client.rb] updated file contents /var/chef/runs/a679dc7b-3cbf-4d43-9bc8-5ae0223d3b5f/client.rb
[2016-12-15T13:58:12+00:00] INFO: Processing file[/var/chef/runs/a679dc7b-3cbf-4d43-9bc8-5ae0223d3b5f/attribs.json] action create (/var/lib/aws/opsworks/cache.internal/cookbooks/aws_opsworks_custom_run/providers/default.rb line 114)
[2016-12-15T13:58:12+00:00] INFO: file[/var/chef/runs/a679dc7b-3cbf-4d43-9bc8-5ae0223d3b5f/attribs.json] created file /var/chef/runs/a679dc7b-3cbf-4d43-9bc8-5ae0223d3b5f/attribs.json
[2016-12-15T13:58:12+00:00] INFO: file[/var/chef/runs/a679dc7b-3cbf-4d43-9bc8-5ae0223d3b5f/attribs.json] updated file contents /var/chef/runs/a679dc7b-3cbf-4d43-9bc8-5ae0223d3b5f/attribs.json
[2016-12-15T13:58:12+00:00] INFO: Processing directory[/var/chef/runs/a679dc7b-3cbf-4d43-9bc8-5ae0223d3b5f/data_bags/aws_opsworks_app] action create (/var/lib/aws/opsworks/cache.internal/cookbooks/aws_opsworks_custom_run/providers/default.rb line 124)
[2016-12-15T13:58:12+00:00] INFO: directory[/var/chef/runs/a679dc7b-3cbf-4d43-9bc8-5ae0223d3b5f/data_bags/aws_opsworks_app] created directory /var/chef/runs/a679dc7b-3cbf-4d43-9bc8-5ae0223d3b5f/data_bags/aws_opsworks_app
[2016-12-15T13:58:12+00:00] INFO: Processing directory[/var/chef/runs/a679dc7b-3cbf-4d43-9bc8-5ae0223d3b5f/data_bags/aws_opsworks_instance] action create (/var/lib/aws/opsworks/cache.internal/cookbooks/aws_opsworks_custom_run/providers/default.rb line 124)
[2016-12-15T13:58:12+00:00] INFO: directory[/var/chef/runs/a679dc7b-3cbf-4d43-9bc8-5ae0223d3b5f/data_bags/aws_opsworks_instance] created directory /var/chef/runs/a679dc7b-3cbf-4d43-9bc8-5ae0223d3b5f/data_bags/aws_opsworks_instance
[2016-12-15T13:58:12+00:00] INFO: Processing file[/var/chef/runs/a679dc7b-3cbf-4d43-9bc8-5ae0223d3b5f/data_bags/aws_opsworks_instance/script.json] action create (/var/lib/aws/opsworks/cache.internal/cookbooks/aws_opsworks_custom_run/providers/default.rb line 208)
[2016-12-15T13:58:12+00:00] INFO: file[/var/chef/runs/a679dc7b-3cbf-4d43-9bc8-5ae0223d3b5f/data_bags/aws_opsworks_instance/script.json] created file /var/chef/runs/a679dc7b-3cbf-4d43-9bc8-5ae0223d3b5f/data_bags/aws_opsworks_instance/script.json
[2016-12-15T13:58:12+00:00] INFO: file[/var/chef/runs/a679dc7b-3cbf-4d43-9bc8-5ae0223d3b5f/data_bags/aws_opsworks_instance/script.json] updated file contents /var/chef/runs/a679dc7b-3cbf-4d43-9bc8-5ae0223d3b5f/data_bags/aws_opsworks_instance/script.json
[2016-12-15T13:58:12+00:00] INFO: Processing directory[/var/chef/runs/a679dc7b-3cbf-4d43-9bc8-5ae0223d3b5f/data_bags/aws_opsworks_layer] action create (/var/lib/aws/opsworks/cache.internal/cookbooks/aws_opsworks_custom_run/providers/default.rb line 124)
[2016-12-15T13:58:12+00:00] INFO: directory[/var/chef/runs/a679dc7b-3cbf-4d43-9bc8-5ae0223d3b5f/data_bags/aws_opsworks_layer] created directory /var/chef/runs/a679dc7b-3cbf-4d43-9bc8-5ae0223d3b5f/data_bags/aws_opsworks_layer
[2016-12-15T13:58:12+00:00] INFO: Processing file[/var/chef/runs/a679dc7b-3cbf-4d43-9bc8-5ae0223d3b5f/data_bags/aws_opsworks_layer/node.json] action create (/var/lib/aws/opsworks/cache.internal/cookbooks/aws_opsworks_custom_run/providers/default.rb line 208)
[2016-12-15T13:58:12+00:00] INFO: file[/var/chef/runs/a679dc7b-3cbf-4d43-9bc8-5ae0223d3b5f/data_bags/aws_opsworks_layer/node.json] created file /var/chef/runs/a679dc7b-3cbf-4d43-9bc8-5ae0223d3b5f/data_bags/aws_opsworks_layer/node.json
[2016-12-15T13:58:12+00:00] INFO: file[/var/chef/runs/a679dc7b-3cbf-4d43-9bc8-5ae0223d3b5f/data_bags/aws_opsworks_layer/node.json] updated file contents /var/chef/runs/a679dc7b-3cbf-4d43-9bc8-5ae0223d3b5f/data_bags/aws_opsworks_layer/node.json
[2016-12-15T13:58:12+00:00] INFO: Processing directory[/var/chef/runs/a679dc7b-3cbf-4d43-9bc8-5ae0223d3b5f/data_bags/aws_opsworks_stack] action create (/var/lib/aws/opsworks/cache.internal/cookbooks/aws_opsworks_custom_run/providers/default.rb line 124)
[2016-12-15T13:58:12+00:00] INFO: directory[/var/chef/runs/a679dc7b-3cbf-4d43-9bc8-5ae0223d3b5f/data_bags/aws_opsworks_stack] created directory /var/chef/runs/a679dc7b-3cbf-4d43-9bc8-5ae0223d3b5f/data_bags/aws_opsworks_stack
[2016-12-15T13:58:12+00:00] INFO: Processing file[/var/chef/runs/a679dc7b-3cbf-4d43-9bc8-5ae0223d3b5f/data_bags/aws_opsworks_stack/a0dc4b91-63dc-4947-95c2-f28d2fae00fb.json] action create (/var/lib/aws/opsworks/cache.internal/cookbooks/aws_opsworks_custom_run/providers/default.rb line 208)
[2016-12-15T13:58:12+00:00] INFO: file[/var/chef/runs/a679dc7b-3cbf-4d43-9bc8-5ae0223d3b5f/data_bags/aws_opsworks_stack/a0dc4b91-63dc-4947-95c2-f28d2fae00fb.json] created file /var/chef/runs/a679dc7b-3cbf-4d43-9bc8-5ae0223d3b5f/data_bags/aws_opsworks_stack/a0dc4b91-63dc-4947-95c2-f28d2fae00fb.json
[2016-12-15T13:58:12+00:00] INFO: file[/var/chef/runs/a679dc7b-3cbf-4d43-9bc8-5ae0223d3b5f/data_bags/aws_opsworks_stack/a0dc4b91-63dc-4947-95c2-f28d2fae00fb.json] updated file contents /var/chef/runs/a679dc7b-3cbf-4d43-9bc8-5ae0223d3b5f/data_bags/aws_opsworks_stack/a0dc4b91-63dc-4947-95c2-f28d2fae00fb.json
[2016-12-15T13:58:12+00:00] INFO: Processing directory[/var/chef/runs/a679dc7b-3cbf-4d43-9bc8-5ae0223d3b5f/data_bags/aws_opsworks_command] action create (/var/lib/aws/opsworks/cache.internal/cookbooks/aws_opsworks_custom_run/providers/default.rb line 124)
[2016-12-15T13:58:12+00:00] INFO: directory[/var/chef/runs/a679dc7b-3cbf-4d43-9bc8-5ae0223d3b5f/data_bags/aws_opsworks_command] created directory /var/chef/runs/a679dc7b-3cbf-4d43-9bc8-5ae0223d3b5f/data_bags/aws_opsworks_command
[2016-12-15T13:58:12+00:00] INFO: Processing file[/var/chef/runs/a679dc7b-3cbf-4d43-9bc8-5ae0223d3b5f/data_bags/aws_opsworks_command/a679dc7b-3cbf-4d43-9bc8-5ae0223d3b5f.json] action create (/var/lib/aws/opsworks/cache.internal/cookbooks/aws_opsworks_custom_run/providers/default.rb line 208)
[2016-12-15T13:58:12+00:00] INFO: file[/var/chef/runs/a679dc7b-3cbf-4d43-9bc8-5ae0223d3b5f/data_bags/aws_opsworks_command/a679dc7b-3cbf-4d43-9bc8-5ae0223d3b5f.json] created file /var/chef/runs/a679dc7b-3cbf-4d43-9bc8-5ae0223d3b5f/data_bags/aws_opsworks_command/a679dc7b-3cbf-4d43-9bc8-5ae0223d3b5f.json
[2016-12-15T13:58:12+00:00] INFO: file[/var/chef/runs/a679dc7b-3cbf-4d43-9bc8-5ae0223d3b5f/data_bags/aws_opsworks_command/a679dc7b-3cbf-4d43-9bc8-5ae0223d3b5f.json] updated file contents /var/chef/runs/a679dc7b-3cbf-4d43-9bc8-5ae0223d3b5f/data_bags/aws_opsworks_command/a679dc7b-3cbf-4d43-9bc8-5ae0223d3b5f.json
[2016-12-15T13:58:12+00:00] INFO: Processing directory[/var/chef/runs/a679dc7b-3cbf-4d43-9bc8-5ae0223d3b5f/data_bags/aws_opsworks_user] action create (/var/lib/aws/opsworks/cache.internal/cookbooks/aws_opsworks_custom_run/providers/default.rb line 124)
[2016-12-15T13:58:12+00:00] INFO: directory[/var/chef/runs/a679dc7b-3cbf-4d43-9bc8-5ae0223d3b5f/data_bags/aws_opsworks_user] created directory /var/chef/runs/a679dc7b-3cbf-4d43-9bc8-5ae0223d3b5f/data_bags/aws_opsworks_user
[2016-12-15T13:58:12+00:00] INFO: Processing directory[/var/chef/runs/a679dc7b-3cbf-4d43-9bc8-5ae0223d3b5f/data_bags/aws_opsworks_elastic_load_balancer] action create (/var/lib/aws/opsworks/cache.internal/cookbooks/aws_opsworks_custom_run/providers/default.rb line 124)
[2016-12-15T13:58:12+00:00] INFO: directory[/var/chef/runs/a679dc7b-3cbf-4d43-9bc8-5ae0223d3b5f/data_bags/aws_opsworks_elastic_load_balancer] created directory /var/chef/runs/a679dc7b-3cbf-4d43-9bc8-5ae0223d3b5f/data_bags/aws_opsworks_elastic_load_balancer
[2016-12-15T13:58:12+00:00] INFO: Processing directory[/var/chef/runs/a679dc7b-3cbf-4d43-9bc8-5ae0223d3b5f/data_bags/aws_opsworks_rds_db_instance] action create (/var/lib/aws/opsworks/cache.internal/cookbooks/aws_opsworks_custom_run/providers/default.rb line 124)
[2016-12-15T13:58:12+00:00] INFO: directory[/var/chef/runs/a679dc7b-3cbf-4d43-9bc8-5ae0223d3b5f/data_bags/aws_opsworks_rds_db_instance] created directory /var/chef/runs/a679dc7b-3cbf-4d43-9bc8-5ae0223d3b5f/data_bags/aws_opsworks_rds_db_instance
[2016-12-15T13:58:12+00:00] INFO: Processing directory[/var/chef/runs/a679dc7b-3cbf-4d43-9bc8-5ae0223d3b5f/data_bags/aws_opsworks_ecs_cluster] action create (/var/lib/aws/opsworks/cache.internal/cookbooks/aws_opsworks_custom_run/providers/default.rb line 124)
[2016-12-15T13:58:12+00:00] INFO: directory[/var/chef/runs/a679dc7b-3cbf-4d43-9bc8-5ae0223d3b5f/data_bags/aws_opsworks_ecs_cluster] created directory /var/chef/runs/a679dc7b-3cbf-4d43-9bc8-5ae0223d3b5f/data_bags/aws_opsworks_ecs_cluster
[2016-12-15T13:58:12+00:00] WARN: Skipping final node save because override_runlist was given
[2016-12-15T13:58:12+00:00] INFO: Chef Run complete in 30.522850769 seconds
[2016-12-15T13:58:12+00:00] INFO: Skipping removal of unused files from the cache
[2016-12-15T13:58:12+00:00] INFO: Running report handlers
[2016-12-15T13:58:12+00:00] INFO: Report handlers complete

[2016-12-15T13:58:13+00:00] INFO: Started chef-zero at chefzero://localhost:8889 with repository at /var/chef
One version per cookbook
data_bags at /var/chef/runs/a679dc7b-3cbf-4d43-9bc8-5ae0223d3b5f/data_bags
nodes at /var/chef/runs/a679dc7b-3cbf-4d43-9bc8-5ae0223d3b5f/nodes

[2016-12-15T13:58:13+00:00] INFO: Forking chef instance to converge...
[2016-12-15T13:58:13+00:00] INFO: *** Chef 12.16.42 ***
[2016-12-15T13:58:13+00:00] INFO: Platform: x86_64-linux
[2016-12-15T13:58:13+00:00] INFO: Chef-client pid: 3500
[2016-12-15T13:58:14+00:00] INFO: HTTP Request Returned 404 Not Found: Object not found: chefzero://localhost:8889/nodes/script.localdomain
[2016-12-15T13:58:14+00:00] INFO: Setting the run_list to ["recipe[cassandra-php-driver::setup]", "recipe[security::setup]"] from CLI options
[2016-12-15T13:58:14+00:00] INFO: Run List is [recipe[cassandra-php-driver::setup], recipe[security::setup]]
[2016-12-15T13:58:14+00:00] INFO: Run List expands to [cassandra-php-driver::setup, security::setup]
[2016-12-15T13:58:14+00:00] INFO: Starting Chef Run for script.localdomain
[2016-12-15T13:58:14+00:00] INFO: Running start handlers
[2016-12-15T13:58:14+00:00] INFO: Start handlers complete.
[2016-12-15T13:58:14+00:00] INFO: HTTP Request Returned 404 Not Found: Object not found: 
[2016-12-15T13:58:14+00:00] INFO: HTTP Request Returned 412 Precondition Failed: No such cookbook: apt

================================================================================
Error Resolving Cookbooks for Run List:
================================================================================

Missing Cookbooks:
------------------
No such cookbook: apt

Expanded Run List:
------------------
* cassandra-php-driver::setup
* security::setup

Platform:
---------
x86_64-linux

[2016-12-15T13:58:14+00:00] ERROR: Running exception handlers
[2016-12-15T13:58:14+00:00] ERROR: Exception handlers complete
[2016-12-15T13:58:14+00:00] FATAL: Stacktrace dumped to /var/chef/runs/a679dc7b-3cbf-4d43-9bc8-5ae0223d3b5f/local-mode-cache/cache/chef-stacktrace.out
[2016-12-15T13:58:14+00:00] FATAL: Please provide the contents of the stacktrace.out file if you file a bug report
[2016-12-15T13:58:14+00:00] ERROR: 412 "Precondition Failed"
[2016-12-15T13:58:14+00:00] FATAL: Chef::Exceptions::ChildConvergeError: Chef run process exited unsuccessfully (exit code 1)
```

Comment: Make the cloud formation template not roll back on failure for a start.. under advanced you'll find this option. Then SSH on to the server thats not building properly and find the opsworks/chef logs to have a read.  or view the logs from the opsworks UI area now that the template rollback isn't happening.

Comment: @PaulDunlop  In fact, I successfuly create the instance manually with the cookbook. but when I use the template It always fails on seup/start. I added the logs 
does anyone please know how to solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the error message, it sounds like your transitive cookbook dependencies (`apt`) are not present in your cookbook repository.

Apparently AWS OpsWorks' Berkshelf support has changed between versions. Only the Chef 11.10 OpsWorks release had [built-in Berkshelf support](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/opsworks/latest/userguide/workingcookbook-chef11-10.html#workingcookbook-chef11-10-berkshelf), but then was subsequently pulled from the [Chef 12](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/opsworks/latest/userguide/chef-12-linux.html) OpsWorks release.

If your CloudFormation-managed OpsWorks stack is using Chef version 12, and you're not packaging your cookbook dependencies using Berkshelf elsewhere, I would recommend either specifying Chef version 11.10, or following the process specified in the [Packaging Cookbook Dependencies Locally](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/opsworks/latest/userguide/best-practices-packaging-cookbooks-locally.html) documentation to package your cookbook dependencies locally and use the packaged cookbook repository as your custom cookbook source.